# Indenting footnotes in ConTeXt

Tags: indentation, footnotes, context

How to modify

```
\footnote
```

in ConTeXt, such that the complete footnote is indented?

Comment: By default footnotes are not indented. Can you add a complete minimal example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I am not sure, what you are asking for. Yes, footnotes are not indented, but I want them to indent. I think I should modify \setupfootenotes. Of course I can add a minexample (any footnote), if needed. Edit: Ok, my question could be misunderstood: I know there is no indentation, no complete and no first line, but Im looking for that (complete) indentation. Thats the question.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I thought you asked how to get rid of the indentation. So you want the entire footnote to be shifted or only the first line?

Comment: Footnotes respect the *indenting* parameter: ``\setupnotation[footnote][indenting={small,yes}]``.

Comment: Yes, I want the entire footnote to indent.
@phq: This does not work, no indentation of the footnote, where I have to place the \setupnotation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how you want your footnotes to look like and what
to indent. You find further information on the [Wiki -
Footnotes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Footnotes).

Use the `\setupnotation [footnote]` command to adjust the
layout, here are some examples.

```
%% left align the footnote number and shift the footnotes
\setupnotation
  [footnote]
  [alternative=left]

%% indents the entire footnote by 2em and the number by 1em
\setupnotation
  [footnote]
  [alternative=left,
   width=2em,
   numbercommand=\hskip1em]

%% left align the footnote number, which practically indents the
%% first line
\setupnotation
  [footnote]
  [alternative=left,
   hang=1]

%% Indents the first line inclusive the footnote number
\setupnotation
  [footnote]
  [alternative=left,
   numbercommand=\hskip1cm]

%% Indents all footnotes and right-aligns the number
\setupnotation
  [footnote]
  [alternative=left,
   headalign=flushright,
   width=2em]
```

Full example:

```
\setupnotation
  [footnote]
  [alternative=left,
   hang=1,
   numbercommand=\hskip1cm]

\starttext

Lorem \startfootnote
        \input ward
      \stopfootnote

Ipsum \startfootnote
        \input ward
      \stopfootnote

\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: That works, but I want to indent the entire footnote, not only it's first line. In LaTeX that is
    \deffootnote{2em}{2em}{\textsuperscript{\normalfont \thefootnotemark} }

Comment: The footnote number as well?

Comment: Yes, everything (f.e.) 2em to the right.

Comment: Something like `\setupnotation[footnote][alternative=left,width=2em,numbercommand=\hskip1em]`?

Comment: Yes, the indentation works now, but it's not perfect like the above LaTeX code (and thats my aim, sorry for not concrete telling that before). One picture of what I want to achieve:

http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/818/footexample.jpg

Comment: `numbercommand=\hskip1.6em\high`

Comment: One more question: If the footnote number has two decimals, than there is no space between the number and the text. How to fix that?

Comment: The space between the last decimal of the footnotenumber and the first character of the text should be always the same, independent of the numbers of decimals. In Latex I do this by `\deffootnote{2em}{2em}{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\thefootnotemark} }` - changing the parameters did not help, can you give an example how to change correctly?

Comment: Add `headalign=flushright`. If that's not what you want, then I would suggest to update your question accordingly.

Comment: It is not perfect, but it is ok for now. Perfectly I would have always, in every footnote, exactly the same space between the last digit and the first letter of the text. But maybe that is hard to realize. Thank you for now.

Comment: @Mustafa I added another example. I get the same space between digit and text. If that does not work for you, you can consider to open another question with addresses this.

Comment: Ok, the last example seems to work, thank you!